# background image sprite in svg image? [how to show only a small cropped portion of a large image]

Tags: css, image, svg, sprite

crop a large picture as css background image sprite, for an HTML img element, this is working:
the img.src is a svg defined transparent size100x100 pic just to hold its height and width, then in style background is the true picture, a specified slot from a large composite png picture:

```
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22100%22%20height%3D%22100%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20100%20100%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22100%22%20height%3D%22100%22%20fill%3D%22rgba%28255%2C255%2C255%2C0.1%29%22%3E%3C/rect%3E%3C/svg%3E"
   class="rounded-circle"
   style="background: url('/path/to/large.png') -500px -2900px"
   alt="alt name">
```

it's working in normal HTML document,

Right now I need it in a large SVG graph, mainly because in a D3 Data Visualization project, the svg is generated by d3 I want to insert different sprite of the composite png to show in different position of the D3 chart, however similar syntax isn't working:

```
<svg ...>
  <image href="the-transparent-foreground-png-or-svg"
     style="background: url(/path/to/large.png) -500px -2900px" />
</svg>
```

because inside a svg tag, it's called `<image>` and use `href`; but however the background style seems not applying
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image

It's not exactly duplicates because below answer has clipPath as well that 's better answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVG elements don't support the HTML `background` properties.  If you want the image to ap[pear in the SVG, then you have to explicitly put it there yourself as another svg element.

```
<svg ...>
  <image href="/path/to/large.png" ... />
  <image href="the-transparent-foreground-png-or-svg"/>
</svg>
```

But since the second image is transparent, it is pointless and can be removed.

If you want to only show part of `large.png`, then you'll need to mask or clip it, and position it carefully.

You'll probably want something like the following:

```
<svg ...>

  <defs>
    <clipPath id="square100">
      <rect width="100" height="100"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>

  <g clip-path="url(#square100)">
    <image href="/path/to/large.png" transform="translate(-500 -2900)" ... />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I can confirm this approach works in Chrome, then today I realized it's not working in Firefox, even the current latest firefox61 beta as of today, so is this g clip with image is somewhat standard? or firefox has problem of conforming standard?

Comment: It should be working - although I had a typo in there (units in the transform) which I have now removed.  See [this jsfiddle test](https://jsfiddle.net/Lzpfy6pL/3/) which works in both browsers.  If you have an example that doesn't work, try asking a new question.

Comment: this special question is still different from the marked duplicate,  by image sprite, I meant to show only a small cropped portion of a large image, in the case it's still different than your jsfiddle example of cropping a rect;
But however I figured out the firefox difference is firefox requires to mark the large image's width and height, like
`<g clip-path=...><imgage href="..." width="1000" height="3000" transform="translate(-500,-2900)" /></g>`
The Chrome seems able to recognize the image's original width and height automatically; but firefox cannot.

Comment: Yes. Automatic width and height (similar behaviour to HTML) is a feature that is part of the upcoming SVG2 specification.  It is something that Chrome has alreadyadded support for, but Firefox has not.  SVG 1.1 requires that width and height be specified.